# How to set URI limit for GET requests in Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I'm making a GET request to an internal endpoint, and passing a large amount of data in the URI. Tornado is rejecting the request with Error: 414 URI too large. I know we can pass config arguments to Tornado when spinning up a web server, and I know URI max size is typically a configurable setting. The problem is, I can't find a list of parameter names I can define with options.define(), or in a config file.

So my question is: How can I increase the maximum URI size in Tornado?

I know I could use a POST request, or batch the requests, etc, but I'm trying to use existing endpoints, if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: A GET is definitely not the method for sending this data if you are hitting this limit. Why can you not change this method to a POST?

Comment: It's not that I can't, but rather that I'm trying to use existing endpoints. Thanks

Comment: I would suggest changing the endpoint. Better to make improvements to the application than using the wrong thing for the wrong job

Comment: I appreciate that, Iain. It's a tricky one, since the GET simply retrieves data, and has no consequence on the server. According REST principles, this should be a GET, but obviously, for this amount of data, we should rethink our strategy. That being said, I'd still like to know how to configure this parameter, or see a list of Tornado configurable parameters, at least for my own knowledge. Thanks

Comment: Okay fair enough :) What is in the GET data and can you change the endpoint?

Comment: Tornado doesn't provide any option to configure URI length. All the configurable options related to the http server can be found in the [`HTTPServer`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpserver.html#tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer) class. There are `max_body_size` and `max_header_size` options, but URI is sent the first line of the HTTP request, so that's not part of the headers. But you can try changing that option.

Comment: The request contains a query string with a list of user_id's. Changing the endpoint not ideal, but must inevitably happen. I was hoping we could increase the URI size limit to get around the issue, since this is an internal microservice with no public endpoints.

Comment: You can try changing the `max_header_size` value. It's set to `65536` (64KiB) by default. But this will only work if Tornado internally sees the Request Line as part of the Request Headers.  In this case you'll have to use `HTTPServer` instance to start the server as shown in this code: https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.Application

Comment: Yeah, looks like we are using HTTPServer to start the server already, so that's very convenient. I agree with your first comment, in that it doesn't seem like this setting should work, based solely on the name, but I can try it at least. Thanks xyres.